# Divisibility and finding the remainder

Tags: divisibility

If $11n$ leaves a remainder of 6 when divided by 7, what is the remainder when $5n$ is divided 7?

Comment: Sounds like a good homework problem, what are your thoughts?

Comment: Voting to close.  What is the point of asking other people to do your homework for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
11n &\equiv& 6 &\pmod 7 \\
4n &\equiv& 6 &\pmod 7 \\
3(4n) &\equiv& 3(6) &\pmod 7 \\
12n &\equiv& 4 &\pmod 7 \\
5n &\equiv& 4 &\pmod 7 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Its not a homework. Its a question from a contest

Comment: Can you explain further sir. We dont have modular arithmetic in grade 8